# Many segmentation faults in applications after RAM upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, ram, segmentation-fault

I have a Lenovo IdeaCentre 510A-15ARR on which I replaced Windows 10 Home with Kubuntu. Here is some basic info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.5 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop System: LENOVO product: 90J0000VIX v: ideacentre 510A-15ARR
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 36EE UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO 
           BIOS version: O3TKT50A date: 09/01/2020 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 2400G with Radeon Vega Graphics bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           Speed: 1404 MHz min/max: 1600/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1402 2: 1417 3: 1640 4: 1555 5: 1587 6: 1489 7: 1414 
           8: 1403 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X] driver: amdgpu v: 5.9.10.20.50 
           Device-2: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] driver: N/A 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu FAILED: ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX550/550 Series v: 4.6.14756 Core Profile Context 20.50 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-3: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor driver: N/A 
           Device-4: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-5: N/A type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-48-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 6c:4b:90:77:7e:56 
           IF-ID-1: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: 02:42:4d:35:1c:75 
           IF-ID-2: veth2367ad2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 1e:a4:51:12:e9:c2 
           IF-ID-3: veth4a6a7c1 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 0a:eb:5c:cb:77:a0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 307.54 GiB (26.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLW256HEHP-000L7 size: 238.47 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-08WN4A0 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 233.24 GiB used: 153.77 GiB (65.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 59.9 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 46 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 2406 
Info:      Processes: 358 Uptime: 5h 47m Memory: 14.65 GiB used: 4.77 GiB (32.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

It is sold with 2 x 4 GB DDR4 SDRAM memory banks, speed 2666 MHz. I've upgraded my RAM replacing them with [2 X 8 GB 288pin DIMM DDR4 - 2666MHz, Unbuffered, 1,2V](https://www.compuram.biz/memory/lenovo/desktop-workstation/ideacentre/500-series/510a/8gb-4x70r38787-x9953.htm).
Now I'm experiencing a lot of segmentation faults with the apps I use most (Chrome, WebStorm) with the result that sometimes a tab crashes.

```
[16361.384052] ThreadPoolForeg[29828]: segfault at 0 ip 00005649f42b5a83 sp 00007f80140cdfc0 error 4 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[16361.384079] Code: 01 66 f0 0f b1 4b 06 75 d4 0f b7 43 04 48 83 c3 08 0f b7 c0 25 fc ff 00 00 48 8d 0d 87 57 f1 05 48 8b 09 48 8b 09 48 8b 04 41 <4c> 8b 38 4c 8b 77 10 48 63 47 18 4c 8d 24 80 49 c1 e4 04 4f 8b 2c
[16609.060966] traps: chrome[30182] general protection fault ip:5649f7a84c8d sp:7ffdd2c0d8f0 error:0 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[16618.258802] ThreadPoolForeg[30451]: segfault at 51de0833a49 ip 00005649f3a45de2 sp 00007f801d50bf80 error 4 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[16618.258815] Code: ff e8 12 49 0a 00 84 c0 74 19 48 8b b5 a8 fe ff ff 48 39 75 90 74 0c 48 8d bd 48 ff ff ff e8 05 f9 09 00 4c 8b a5 80 fe ff ff <8a> 03 3c 4d 0f 87 f5 8e 00 00 0f b6 c0 48 8d 0d 5a ea a4 fd 48 63
[17042.059692] ThreadPoolForeg[30496]: segfault at 0 ip 00005649f42b5a83 sp 00007f8011f13fc0 error 4 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[17042.059701] Code: 01 66 f0 0f b1 4b 06 75 d4 0f b7 43 04 48 83 c3 08 0f b7 c0 25 fc ff 00 00 48 8d 0d 87 57 f1 05 48 8b 09 48 8b 09 48 8b 04 41 <4c> 8b 38 4c 8b 77 10 48 63 47 18 4c 8d 24 80 49 c1 e4 04 4f 8b 2c
[19140.331647] traps: chrome[31778] general protection fault ip:5649f7a863c5 sp:7ffdd2c0e2a0 error:0 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[20341.982091] ThreadPoolForeg[33421]: segfault at 1b8643e03a90 ip 00005649f3a45de2 sp 00007f8011f0ef80 error 4 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[20341.982101] Code: ff e8 12 49 0a 00 84 c0 74 19 48 8b b5 a8 fe ff ff 48 39 75 90 74 0c 48 8d bd 48 ff ff ff e8 05 f9 09 00 4c 8b a5 80 fe ff ff <8a> 03 3c 4d 0f 87 f5 8e 00 00 0f b6 c0 48 8d 0d 5a ea a4 fd 48 63
[20503.497110] traps: ThreadPoolForeg[36265] general protection fault ip:5649f42b6901 sp:7f8016bd4f80 error:0 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[20602.003698] traps: chrome[36448] general protection fault ip:5649f42b6901 sp:7ffdd2c0f120 error:0 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
[20692.904604] traps: chrome[36620] general protection fault ip:5649f42b6901 sp:7ffdd2c0f0e0 error:0 in chrome[5649f1a20000+7fcb000]
```

I've performed a memtest with PassMark MemTest86 v9.0 Free and all tests passed.
All the software should be updated, also the [Radeon driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-50) is correctly installed.
These crashes must be related to the new RAM but I really cannot understand why they occur, since the sticks should be compatible (like the others I bought when I had Windows), but it seems I cannot have a very stable system whenever I upgrade it.
Any advice?

Comment: AMD Ryzen processors are very fussy about RAM. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema memtest passed

Comment: Sorry, what does "memtest with PassMark 9" mean?  If it means some memory test that is part of the program "PassMark 9", then that's different from the `memtest86` that was suggested.

Comment: @Ray PassMark I meant PassMark MemTest86 v9.0 Free (PassMark it's the company name), the ISO version.

Comment: Oh, I see!  I guess what I was thinking of was [this](http://www.memtest.org/), which is available as an Ubuntu package called [memtest86+](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/memtest86+).  I don't know about the one by PassMark, but if you believe in it, then I guess that's ok.  What you describe feels like a memory chip problem.  So, even if it passed the tests, I would still suspect the memory chips.  Can you run another OS off a USB drive for a while and see if you see any problems?

Comment: @Ray the one you say should be the same available with Ubuntu, listed in the Grub options. Unfortunately, it freezes at 28%, maybe related to UEFI (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267257/why-does-memtest-keep-freezing)

Comment: I suppose so...  Or it could be a problem with your memory chips?  Well, how about this...  You replaced 2 x 4 GB with 2 x 8 GB.  So, you still have your 4 GB chips?  If you put them back, does (a) memtest86+ work and (b) do you get any segmentation faults any more?  If it's (a) yes and (b) no [or even just "(b) no"], then maybe it's the chips?

Comment: Replacing the old memory chips of 4 GB I don't get any segfaults. The thing I cannot understand is that it's the second time I try to upgrade the RAM, how could it be even statistically possible that both (the first Cruzer, the second Samsung) are corrupted?
In addition to that I see that the RAM frequency now is 2932MHz despite I've bought a 2666MHz...

Comment: Remember I said that AMD Ryzens are fussy about RAM? If memtest freezes at 28%, more than likely it's still a RAM problem. When you upgraded RAM, if you're using both Cruzer and Samsung DIMMS, that's probably your problem. You really can't mix and match RAM. Try any 4G DIMM with a 8G DIMM, rerun memtest, then replace the 8G DIMM with the OTHER 8G DIMM, and rerun memtest.

Comment: Your RAM frequencies are also suspect. Are you sure you got the correct RAM for your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already observed that you also have problems with Windows on that machine, this is very obviously a hardware problem. So you know about memtest; why didn't you try that first? Exactly what do you expect here?

Apart from the obvious suspicion that the RAM is simply defective, it might be an overheating problem, causing a crack on the mainboard when inserting the RAM, insufficient power supply.

I am pretty sure that the least of your problems are Linux drivers.

Comment: I'm expecting a hint, an advice or something I ignore. The memtest completely passed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

**AMD Ryzen processors are very fussy about RAM.**

Go to memtest86.com and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

`memtest` freezes at 28%. **You have a RAM problem with the new 8G DIMMS you installed.**

re: *How could it be even statistically possible that both (the first Cruzer, the second Samsung) are corrupted?*

You can't mix and match RAM.

Try any 4G DIMM with a 8G DIMM, rerun memtest, then replace the 8G DIMM with the OTHER 8G DIMM, and rerun memtest. Look for freezes, BSOD, or segfaults.

re: *I see that the RAM frequency now is 2932MHz despite I've bought a 2666MHz.*

Your RAM frequencies are also suspect. Are you sure you got the correct RAM for your computer?

Check your BIOS and confirm that your CPU and RAM are NOT overclocked.

**Update #1:**

Lenovo IdeaCentre 510A-15ARR

LENOVO product: **90J0**000VIX

Serial: XXXXXXX

You have BIOS version: O3TKT50A dated: 09/01/2020. **It's possible that this is an older version, or an incorrect version for your model/product/serial.**

**A newer/different BIOS version O4DKT41A is available** [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds503427-bios-for-windows-10-64-bit-ideacentre-510a-15arr). Installation instructions are on this web page, and also shown below. Read them carefully!

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Flash Under Operating System**

1. Please make note of any settings you have changed in the BIOS Setup utility. They may have to be re-entered after updating the BIOS.
2. Click on the Start button and type cmd.exe. Right-click on the cmd.exe application and select run as administrator to open the Command Prompt with Administrator privilege.
3. In the "Command Prompt" window, change to the directory where the above files were extracted. The command to go to the location is "cd C:\SWTOOLS\FLASH\O4DJYnnUSA", where "nn" represents the two digit flash level.
4. Enter the command "flash.cmd" and press the Enter key to start the flashing process.
5. You may first see a confirmation prompt "Proceed with BIOS update now?". Click "Yes" to continue.
6. You will see the prompt "Would you like to update the Serial Number?". Input "n" and press Enter.
7. Then you will see the prompt "Would you like to update the Machine Type and Model?". Input "n" and press Enter again. Then the BIOS update process will start.
8. The update may take up to 2 minutes. Do not power off or restart the system during this procedure! After the Windows update process ends, the system will automatically reboot to continue the flash process.
9. After the system reboots, the BIOS update process will continue with a simple graphic UI. When the BIOS update process ends, the system will reboot automatically.
10. The BIOS update process ends with above nine steps.

**Notes**: You may see a POST error "0162: Setup data integrity checkfailure" after step 9. Press F1 to enter BIOS Setup Utility, and then press F10 to save your settings.

Comment: when I said I used both brands, I meant without mixing, I used them in pairs of the same brand. So, 2 X 8 GB Cruzer lead to BSOD in Windows, 2 X 8GB Samsung lead to seg faults in Kubuntu, the system is stable just with the original 2 X 4GB Samsung.
memtest86 passes all tests (4/4), as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Chris Run the 2nd test from my answer, looking for `memtest` freezes, BSOD or segfautls. Recheck that the 8G DIMMS have the corrrect frequency for your motherboard. Make sure your CPU and RAM are NOT overclocked.

Comment: About the frequencies, the reseller linked to this article: https://www.compuram.de/blog/en/q-a-matching-clock-speeds-for-your-memory-upgrade/. So they seem to sell RAM with higher frequencies and then being clocked by the system bus.

Comment: @Chris re: *"I see that the RAM frequency now is 2932MHz despite I've bought a 2666MHz"* sounds like your DIMMS are under-speced, no?

Comment: I meant that the reseller sold the RAM as 2666MHz (from the website), actually, the frequency is higher, but according to them (following what's in the article), that shouldn't be a problem, since the frequency is clocked by the system bus.

Comment: @Chris If the RAM is 2666Mhz, but being clocked at 2932Mhz, they're overclocked... if I'm reading your comment correctly. Confirm in your BIOS that CPU and RAM are NOT overclocked. Did you do the 4G/8G test I proposed?

Comment: @Chris Give me the serial # of your Lenovo IdeaCentre 510A-15ARR. I'm looking for a BIOS update, but can't find it at the Lenovo site without a serial #.

Comment: @Chris Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a dual boot system, so I can't use it and also a Lenovo staff member doesn't know if it even exists a different BIOS flashing tool. Game over.

Comment: @Chris  You may be able to flash the BIOS using FreeDOS http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: @Chris Did you run the 4G/8G test that I proposed earlier?

Comment: @Chris Did you confirm that the CPU and RAM are not overclocked in the BIOS?

Comment: @Chris Status please...

Comment: I'll do some more tests on the week end, now I'm working. I haven't overclocked anything and the BIOS version is probably different. I read on Lenovo forum that BIOS version changes just the last part (O3TKT50A, O3TKT50B, O3TKT50C, O3TKT51A, etc), the one shown probably doens't apply to my machine, in fact flashing that version doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the update. I agree... the BIOS numbering is suspect... but I can't find older 03xxxxxx BIOS, even with the serial #. Do the 4G/8G test first.